# Need help in restructuring data with JSONata

Tags: json, jsonata

I cant get it done, need some community brainpower here. Please find the source data and the desired results below. I am currently familiarizing myself with JSONata.

I have tried almost all combinations in the JSONata docs, but I am getting strange results back.

##### Source data

```json
[
  {
    "id": 784521,
    "name": "T-Shirt - Red / 60 XXL",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "customization",
        "value": "Text, Logo"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_text",
        "value": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_text_pos",
        "value": "Left"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_logo",
        "value": "https://https://picsum.photos/200/300"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_logo_pos",
        "value": "Right"
      }
    ],
    "quantity": 8,
    "sku": "888-111"
  },{
    "id": 154857,
    "name": "Pullover - Blue / 48 L",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "customization",
        "value": "Text"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_text",
        "value": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "name": "customization_text_pos",
        "value": "Right"
      }
    ],
    "quantity": 4,
    "sku": "555-111"
  }
]
```

##### Desired result

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "T-Shirt - Red / 60 XXL",
      "quantity": 8,
      "customization": "Text, Logo",
      "customization_text": "John Doe",
      "customization_text_pos": "Left",
      "customization_logo": "https://https://picsum.photos/200/300",
      "customization_logo_pos": "Right"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pullover - Blue / 48 L",
      "quantity": 4,
      "customization": "Text",
      "customization_text": "John Doe",
      "customization_text_pos": "Right",
      "customization_logo": "",
      "customization_logo_pos": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how important for your case to populate the missing properties with an empty string value, but if not - reducing your properties array into an object lets you achieve the result:

```
{
  "products": $$.(
    $item := $;
    
    properties{
      "name": $item.name,
      "quantity": $item.quantity,
      name: value 
    }
  )
}
```

See it live: https://stedi.link/6htarTz

Comment: Thank you! That’s it. Populating the missing properties with an empty string is not necessary.